Invalid digital certificate and certificate details missing
I am trying to attach the certificate in the digitally signed pdf document with PDFBOX in JAVA.
I didn't get any error during the whole process of attaching the certificate and signature. I am using a certificate and signature the Certificate Authority (CA) provided.
Then, when I try to open that PDF in Acrobat Adobe, it gives an error that says the certificate is invalid and the certificate details are not present in the signature panel.
I tried to check if the signature field is present or not with this line of code and I can say the signature field is present in pdf file.
What could be the cause of the not showing the certificate details?

The signature details pop should be visible the certificate should be valid, and it should say that the file is certified by XXXX.
private void attachNotariusVerifiedCertificate(String signRequestId, FileOutputStream output, PDDocument unsignedDocument) throws Exception
   {
      loadExternalCert(eSignCertProvider.getCertificateChain());
      ExternalSigningSupport externalSigningSupport = unsignedDocument.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);
      byte[] cmsSignature = signExternally(externalSigningSupport.getContent(), signRequestId);
      externalSigningSupport.setSignature(cmsSignature);
   }

private byte[] signExternally(InputStream content, String signRequestId) throws IOException
   {
      List<Certificate> externalCertificates;
      JcaCertStore jcaCertStore;
      CMSSignedDataGenerator generator;
      MessageDigest messageDigest;
      byte[] documentHash;
      byte[] signedDocumentHash;
      ContentSigner contentSigner;
      JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder jcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
      try {
         externalCertificates = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(externalCertificateChain));
         jcaCertStore = new JcaCertStore(externalCertificates);
         generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
         generator.addCertificates(jcaCertStore);
         messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
         documentHash = messageDigest.digest(content.readAllBytes());
         signedDocumentHash = eSignCertProvider.signDocumentHash(documentHash, signRequestId);
         contentSigner = new ContentSigner()
         {
            @Override
            public byte[] getSignature() {
               return signedDocumentHash;
            }

            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
               return new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
               return new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA256WithRSA");
            }
         };
         jcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build());
         jcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder.setDirectSignature(true);
         org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate certificateX509 = org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate.getInstance(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(externalCertificateChain[0].getEncoded()));
         generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(jcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder.build(contentSigner, new X509CertificateHolder(org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate.getInstance(X509CertificateStructure.getInstance(certificateX509)))));
         CMSSignedData signedData = generator.generate(new CMSAbsentContent(), false);
         return signedData.getEncoded();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         loggingService.error(LOGGER_NAME, "Exception in signExternally()", e);
         throw new IOException(e);
      }
   }

public byte[] signDocumentHash(byte[] hash, String signRequestId) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] signedDocumentHash;
        ASN1EncodableVector digestInfoVector;
        DERSequence derSequence;
        String base64DigestInfo;
        String requestBodyJson;
        String signedPayload;
        String response;
        String signatureBase64;
        try {
            digestInfoVector = new ASN1EncodableVector();
            digestInfoVector.add(new AlgorithmIdentifier(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256, DERNull.INSTANCE));
            digestInfoVector.add(new DEROctetString(hash));
            derSequence = new DERSequence(digestInfoVector);
            base64DigestInfo = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(derSequence.getEncoded());
            requestBodyJson = signRequestPayload(base64DigestInfo, signRequestId);
            signedPayload = signedPayload(requestBodyJson, serverConfig.geteSignConfig().getSignatureKey());
            response = sign(signedPayload).getBody();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Map map = objectMapper.readValue(response, Map.class);
            signatureBase64 = map.get("sig").toString();
            signedDocumentHash = Base64.getDecoder().decode(String.valueOf(signatureBase64.toCharArray()));
            return signedDocumentHash;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            loggingService.error(LOGGER_NAME, "Exception in sign document hash reason:: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }


This is the whole code we use.

Please share the signed PDF for analysis.

@mkl Here is the Signed Pdf
https://uploadnow.io/files/jbH2sC2

This question appears identical to this (now deleted -- requires 10K rep to see) question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78997785/238704

"Here is the Signed Pdf https://uploadnow.io/files/jbH2sC2" - that leads to some login screen. Please provide credentials to use there. Or even better, make the PDF directly accessible.

https://fileport.io/tkMaf9xaUrrY
Try this one.

Your signature is only zeroes. Likely a coding error, i.e. the actual signature is missing. Did you use the example code to sign (likely not) or what is the code that you used?

"Your signature is only zeroes." - Not only that, the signature also is in a compressed object stream. That cannot work. And the file is single-revision only which clearly cannot result from using the PDFBox example code.

https://ctxt.io/2/AAC4gkEuFg
Please refer to this to see the code.
(valid for a day only)

Yes, I did debug. but it is not zeros. It's byte[] (non zeros)
I have edited the question and added the code .

Which PDFBox version exactly are you using? I'd like to run your code but want to make sure it runs in the same environment as it does for you.

we are using 3.0.2.

3.0.3 has been released over a month ago.

Did you find any mistakes in the code?
Or are there any suggestions that we should make about it?

I didn't find any. This doesn't mean they aren't any, just that I didn't find it. Maybe I missed something obvious. The best would be to have a working project. You don't even need the signing code, just some random bytes assignment to cmsSignature so that you or we can find out by debugging why these bytes don't get written to the file.

Is there any possibility that the certificate and signature that I am fetching from CA APIs
it's not valid or corrupted?

You wrote that cmsSignature isn't all zero when used as parameter for setSignature(). So we should find out why it is all zero in the PDF.

Can you please tell me how you checked that the signature is only zeros?

I used PDFDebugger and looked at Root/Pages/Kids/[0]/Annots/[0]/V/Contents.

Okay, thanks. Please let me know if you find any other mistake that I might be doing.
